# jQuery loading screen on form submit with file response

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML form. When submitted it creates an Excel file and returns it.
On all other forms I have a loading screen shown in the `onSubmit` function and hidden in the `document.ready` function, but when a file is returned, there is no `document.ready` and so my loading screen doesnt hide.

I tried jQuery form plugin with callback function, but this way I was not able to normally show the response page on the other forms. The same is the case with `$.post()` function with a callback.

All I want is to call my `loadingScreenHide` function when the form submit is finished and leave the rest as normal.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Code i tryed is like:
with form plugin callback function (return true; doesnt seem to work) : 
$('form').ajaxForm(function () {activateDeactivateScreen('hidden'); return true; });

or with post instead:
$.post($('form').attr('action'), $('form').serialize(), function () {activateDeactivateScreen('hidden'); return true; });

the 2 main problems are when i use normal submit i dont have a callback and when i get a callback i dont have the normal submit/page load

i also had the idea of changing my java server pages to save the file temporary and redirecting to a download, but this way i would have to change about 20-30 java sources, so i would prefer a javascript solution

Comment: Could you post your code so we can see the process you use.

Comment: I assume that you're posting your form data to a PHP-script or any other serverside CGI. It processes your data and returns an application/excel mimetype, which forces a download, because the browser can't parse exel documents. So your actual page where you sent form from won't even change. As far as I can see you have to send your data via AJAX an temporarily save your exel file on your server an return a link to the success method of your AJAX call. This link can be opened with `document.location = link;` and force a download again.

Comment: @silvinci: i get these excel files from many different pages (20-30 different servlets) , so changing the java sources would be a lot of work

Answer (score 0):

specify a complete callback in the [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
complete:function(){
$("#loadingScreenID").hide();
}
});
```

and the regular post afterwards

```
$.post();
```

Comment: when i use $.post() function loading screen works, but the file isn't shown for download or my other forms are not redirecting to their response pages. how could this be done ?